# How do I include a phone number and icon on a Jekyll theme?

Tags: include, jekyll, font-awesome

There isn't a parameter for phone numbers under the social contact area in the _config.yml file.

I tried to make one and then added a font awesome icon in the _includes directory but it didn't turn out the way I expected it to work.

For example on my site http://dannguyen.me I have several social icons. I would like to add a FA icon for phone number as well, but I couldn't find any good resources.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd try using the icon in SVG format and insert it into the HTML inline. This would allow you to target it with css as well which can be handy.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/) you should check, which is the correct icon you want (most likely fa-phone).
You can then add the following block to your page:

`<a class="social-btn" href="tel:123456" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone"></i>
</a>`

Which theme are you using? Most likely you'll have to overwrite some of the content here.